# how i can use parent variable in child javascript code?

Tags: javascript, three.js

this code use inheritance in the child i add something in the scene which declared in the parent   how i can do it it get Error in see scene in the child level

```
 function parent    (domElement, renderStatistics) {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    }
function child(domElement) {
    parent.call(this, domElement);
    this.init();
}
child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);

child.prototype.constructor = Young;


child.prototype.init = function () {
function createLab(geometry) {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());
        this.scene.add(mesh);  // this error Cannot call method 'add' of undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
child.prototype.init = function () {
var _this = this;
    function createLab(geometry) {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());
        _this.scene.add(mesh);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the cause of your error is the double equals `= =` on the second line.

Thats causing the attribution of the value to be a boolean and not the instance of new THREE.Mesh as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to create inner function inside init...

Try either

```
child.prototype.init = function () {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());
        this.scene.add(mesh);  // this error Cannot call method 'add' of undefined
}
```

Or

```
function createLab(geometry) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());
    this.scene.add(mesh);  // this error Cannot call method 'add' of undefined
 };

child.prototype.init = function () {
     createLab.call(this, whatever);
}
```